# Adding Load Balancer in ECS (New UI - V2)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

Where I can add application load balancer for ECS (Fargate) in New AWS Web UI?

I were able to add in during Create Service for old UI but can't find it in new V2 UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must select a task definition family first, then you will see the *Load Balancing - optional* section appear beneath the *Networking* section.